# Cant inject checkbox value into spring bean

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, handlebars.js

I am using SpringMVC and tring to read params from form. My bean looks like this :

```
public class ChannelBean {

private Integer id;
private Integer siteId;
private String name;
private Boolean active;
private Boolean premium;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public Boolean getPremium() {
    return premium;
}
public void setPremium(Boolean premium) {
    this.premium = premium;
}
public Integer getSiteId() {
    return siteId;
}
public void setSiteId(Integer siteId) {
    this.siteId = siteId;
}
```

}

And on the front end i have handlebars template :

```
<script id="editFormTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <form id="channelForm" class="form-horizontal" action="/admin/channel/save.action" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="siteId" value="${selectedSiteId}">
        <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="id" value="{{id}}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label channelName">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="{{name}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Premium</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="premium" {{#if premium}}checked{{/if}} value="{{premium}}">
                </div>
            </div>  
        <cms:csrfToken />
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-edit btn-primary has-spinner submitEditButton">Ok<span class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

In the controller in Java when i receive Bean, 'name' value is set properly but premium that comes from checkbox is null ?

Comment: try to change type of premium in your bean from Boolean to String and check two cases: unchecked and checked checkbox. As I remember when it is unchecked no parameter is sent at all.

Comment: Do you have the option to use '<form:checkbox/>' (from [spring tag lib](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html)) ??

Comment: how should i write it using <form:checkbox/> ?

Comment: You'd have to declare/import: `<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="spring" %>` (on top/bottom of your jsp) , you'd (have to) use `<spring:form/>` instead of the (plain)
 `<form/>` tag...and with the Boolean binding ("premium"), you'd try: `<spring:checkbox path="premium"/>` (instead of the `<input type="checkbox" />` tag)..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Boolean`  you need to initialise the value to `false` when the page loads. So either initialize `premium` to `false` on the page load OR

change `private Boolean premium` in the *ChannelBean.java* to `private boolean premium`.

Comment: when i change to boolean i get this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when i try to query for items

Comment: okay. then initialize the field with a value. also Debug  and check whether the value is populated correctly

Comment: weird thing is when i open edit view, value is set correctly, so that means that bean is fetched from database correctly. But when i uncheck field that change is not visible inside bean and its sent null

Comment: another problem is when i uncheck checkbox its value dont change